# Looking for alternatives to the database project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, database-project

I've a fairly large database project which contains nine databases and one database with a fairly large schema.

This project takes a large amount of time to build and I'm about to pull my hair out. We'd like to keep our database source controlled, but having a hard getting the other devs to use the project and build the database project before checking in just because it takes so long to build.

It is seriously crippling our work so I'm look for alternatives. Maybe something can be done with Redgate's SQL Compare? I think maybe the only drawback here is that it doesn't validate syntax? Anyone's thoughts/suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to keep your DB Source controlled? this sounds really daft

Comment: unfortunately the application is tightly coupled with the database

Comment: could you explain the situation a little further? does it involve keeping varies db in sync? what specific reasons stop the db's from not being included in the SC?

Comment: We need a repeatably promotion process when moving from dev => integration => pre-prod => prod. Migrating changes up are reliant on the changes being checked in to source control and merging up to their respective branches. The verification and deployment process take a painful amount of time to complete.

Comment: oh I see, right, I'll write up my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider trying SQL Source Control, which is a product designed to work alongside SQL Compare as part of a database development lifecycle. It's in Beta at the moment, but it's feature complete and it's very close to its full release.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

We'd be interested to know how this performs on a commit in comparison to the time it takes for Visual Studio to build your current Database Project. Do you actually need to build the project so often in VS that it's a problem? How large is your schema and how long is an average build?

Comment: build takes 20 mins, faster on computer with SSD. Tested on visual studio 2010 now and its 10 mins; computer with SSD in visual studio 2010 takes less than 5 minutes now. the database project, what goes into source control, is 16 megs.

Comment: I am very excited to try this, however I will need to run it by my team.

Comment: We'd be delighted to set you up with all that you need to pilot this with your team. Your database definitely sounds like it will put any product though its paces! Contact me at David dot Atkinson at Red-Gate dot com.

Comment: Just a FYI - SQL Source Control 1.0 has now shipped! http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

Comment: This product seems misconceived, why would you couple a database directly to source control?  Why not simply allow the generation of scripts to the file system and let these files be checked into source control like any other source code?  I believe the database tool should simply help manage changes to these scripts, and allow a database to be versioned and allow scripts to be generated to convert databases between different versions. It shouldn't need to know the details of your source control repository

Comment: SQL Source Control doesn't need to know the source control details. The product allows two modes of usage. You can link a database to a working folder, which means that it scripts changes to the SQL scripts which you can commit using your preferred version control client, OR you can use a native integration, which provides some basic client functionality within SSMS, allowing you to do the commit without leaving your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping Dev/live db in sync:

There are probably a whole host of ways of doing this, I'm sure other users will expand further (including software solutions).

In my case I use a two fold approach:

(a) run scripts to get differences between db (stored procs, tables, fields, etc)

(b) **Keep a strict log of db changes** (NOT data changes)

In my case I've over time built up a semi structured log thus:

```
Client_Details                  [Alter][Table][New Field]
{
    EnforcePasswordChange;
}

Users                       [Alter][Table][New Field]
{
    PasswordLastUpdated;
}

P_User_GetUserPasswordEnforcement           [New][Stored Procedure]
P_User_UpdateNewPassword                [New][Stored Procedure]
P_User_GetCurrentPassword               [New][Stored Procedure]
P_Doc_BulkDeArchive                     [New][Stored Procedure]
```

ignore the tabing, the markdown has messed it up.

But you get the general gist.

I find that 99% of the time the log is all I need.

Comment: No manual, there are already software solutions as I have mentioned. but I'm operating on the engineering principle of KISS.

Comment: and just to add, the logs are always named in a strict way to:

[Project Name] - [Build/Release Version].

I'm dealing with upwards of 3 large projects at the same time. Without these logs, keeping track of all the changes would be hard. 

Its just a matter of habit, I always have mu log file opened (the project I'm working on) and every time I make a change, I log it. Its not that hard. When it comes to moving to pre-production, just follow the logs. Same goes for then moving to live.